# Given curve $y=2\tan(\pi x/4)$, find tangent line equation at $1$

Tags: derivatives

Given curve $y=2\tan(\pi x/4)$, find tangent line equation when $x=1$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= 2\frac \pi 4 \sec^2\left(\frac{\pi x} 4 \right) = \frac{\pi2}{4\cdot2} =\pi$$ when $x=1$

so how do I find the tangent line equation,
I only know that $y=mx+c$, thus $y=\pi x+c$?

Comment: so I found the point slope equation from other thread, would this be the answer? :y=2tan(pi/4)+pi(x-1)=pi(x)-pi+2

Comment: you have a small error in your equation (last step)

Comment: @Kakayou It was correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find  $y$ at $ x = 1 ;$ ...as $ y = 2 $

The point of tangency is

$$ (1, 2) $$

So the tangent equation is

$$ \frac{y- 2}{x-1} = \pi. $$

Comment: why is it $\sqrt2$? shouldn't it be 2?

Comment: Yes, it is $2$.

Comment: apology, my error